# django-tables2: row number ordering column not in DB

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am using django-tables2 to create a table, How to make the column `row_number` follow the sort of `id` and `age` columns?

https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/master/docs/pages/ordering.rst

```py
import django_tables2 as tables
import itertools

class SimpleTable(tables.Table):
    row_number = tables.Column(empty_values=())
    id = tables.Column()
    age = tables.Column()   

def render_row_number(self):
    self.row_number = getattr(
        self, 'row_number',  itertools.count(self.page.start_index()))
    return next(self.row_number)


def render_id(self, value):
    return f"<{value}"
```

I think the best way is if statement

if asc = `itertools.count(self.page.start_index())`

| row_number | id | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id.1 | age |
| 2 | id.2 | age |
| 3 | id.3 | age |

else desc = `itertools.count(self.page.end_index(), -1)`

| row_number | id | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | id.3 | age |
| 2 | id.2 | age |
| 1 | id.1 | age |

but i don't know how to implant that.

**-- Updated --**

This code works, and it sort id column only, But not column row number!

```py
def order_row_number(self, queryset, is_descending):
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            length=Length('id')
        ).order_by(("-" if is_descending else "") + "length")
        return (queryset, True)
```

But if try to render row number

```py
def render_row_number(self):
        self.row_number = getattr(
            self, 'row_number',  itertools.count(self.page.start_index())
        )
        return next(self.row_number)

def order_row_number(self, queryset, is_descending):
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            length=Length('id')
        ).order_by((
            itertools.count(self.page.end_index(), -1) if is_descending else 
            itertools.count(self.page.start_index())) + "length")
        return (queryset, True)
```

show an error 'SimpleTable' object has no attribute 'page'

Comment: Possibly annotate the position of each item when getting the queryset: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54596555/2785080

Comment: Thanks @Ben `.annotate` got me half way, But i can't sort `row_number` yet.

Comment: What does it mean to sort by `row_number`? is it the same as sorting by `id`? or are you trying to replicate the initial sorting method?

Comment: I am trying to link `row_number` with `id`, So both go together ,see the 2 tables up ( **if asc** ) and ( **else desc**).

Comment: If more than one page of results, do you want the second page of results to start over at row number "1"?